# How to perform an action on random tick using CountDownTimer in Android?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer running in one of my activities like this

```
new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {

        int seconds = (int) l / 1000;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        countdown.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
};
```

My first try was to generate a random int `r` before countdown starts and check if the generated number matches `l` in `onTick` but since `CountDownTimer` is not very accurate the chances of `r` and `l` matching is low...

**so my question how do i perform an action at a random tick?**

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by "CountDownTimer is not very accurate the chances of r and l matching is low "?

Comment: Presuming what you have said is right, you can make a timer in background service passing the random generated number into waiting for 'any_variable'(increasing in loop) equals the passed one.

Comment: I've seen other questions on the accuracy of `CountDownTimer` and from what i can gather `onTick` is not really called in an equal interval, the system calls `onTick` when it's not busy doing something else so if `onTick` was called accurately every 1 millisecond then `r` and `l` would eventually match.

Comment: CountDownTimer is not for it. Use a single shot timer with random interval and trigger next one when finished maybe an answer.